# Scanf recursive function triggers printf twice?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to create a function to get user input which is either 'y' or 'n'.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "userinput.h"

bool userinput_get_yes_or_no(char message[]) {
    printf("%s [y/n]: \n", message);

    char answer;
    scanf_s(" %c", &answer, 1);

    if (answer == 'y') return true;
    if (answer == 'n') return false;

    return userinput_get_yes_or_no(message);
}
```

It works great when the user enters only 'y', 'n'.
When you enter anything else, but only 1 character, it repeats the question, and prints the message once.

BUT
When you enter anything longer than 1 character, the message is repeated multiple times (as many times as characters you entered) before waiting for input again.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hypothesis (because such can be tested and confirmed/rejected): The characters are already entered into the console / std-in and are not discarded  until consumed. So "yy<enter>" will result in *two* 'y' characters being read, one per call, as only one character is consumed at a time.

Comment: Terrible use of recursion. Use a simple do-while loop.

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong"* - you're seemingly assuming `scanf_s(" %c", &answer, 1);` magically clears all characters, both whitespace and non, when reading `stdin`, save for the first one. That's not what it does. If you enter "abc" and extract "a", there's still `"bc" left in the input stream, and your loop happily consumes one for each iteration.

Comment: Using `scanf`, for a start...

Comment: `scanf` means "read the next available character",  not "wait for input"  (roughly speaking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your problem - basically, your control is flowing into the next invocation of your function, and finding something already in the stdin queue. I found a useful answer [here on c-faq.com](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html), and added it in to your function:

```
bool userinput_get_yes_or_no(char message[])
{
    char answer;
    char c; /* for discard */
    printf("%s [y/n]: \n", message);
    scanf_s(" %c", &answer, 1);
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); /* discard */
    if (answer == 'y') {
        return true;
    }
    else if (answer == 'n') { 
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return userinput_get_yes_or_no(message);
    }
}
```

I changed the control flow a little for ease of reading, feel free to disregard. The important part is the line marked discard, where we throw away the rest of the buffer, ensuring there's nothing waiting for the next invocation of the function.